# Output from bpf_printk()

Tags: linux-kernel, llvm-clang, bpf, ebpf

While running some examples from `samples/bpf` I noticed that `bpf_printk` output is prepended with some extra information, e.g. :

```
telnet-470   [001] .N.. 419421.045894: 0x00000001: BPF command: 2
```

`BPF command: 2` is actual string passed to `bpf_printk` in the bpf program, but what is the rest? I assume this comes from kernel's JIT ?

Where can I look closer what those bits mean?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example:

```
telnet-470   [001] .N.. 419421.045894: 0x00000001: BPF command: 2
```

- `telnet` is your current task's name.
- `470` is your current task's PID.
- `001` is the CPU number on which the task is running.
- In `.N..`, each character refers to a set of options (whether irqs are enabled, scheduling options, whether hard/softirqs are running, level of `preempt_disabled` respectively). `N` means that `TIF_NEED_RESCHED` and `PREEMPT_NEED_RESCHED` are set.
- `419421.045894` is a timestamp.
- `0x00000001` is a [fake value used by BPF for the ip register](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.8/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L212).
- `BPF command: 2` is your message.

---

#### Sources

The `bpf_trace_printk` helper [calls `trace_printk`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.8/source/kernel/trace/bpf_trace.c#L212), whose format is detailed in [the documentation for ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) (`Output format` section). The fake ip value is commented in [the original commit for the `bpf_trace_printk` helper](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9c959c863f8217a2ff3d7c296e8223654d240569).

As Qeole mentioned below, this format had nothing to do with the JIT compiler (or the eBPF infrastructure for that matter) and eBPF helpers don't need to be JIT compiled as they're already compiled as part of the kernel's source code.

Comment: Great answer! Regarding the question, I'd just clarify that JIT has nothing to do here. `bpf_trace_printk()` is a helper, so it's not JITted anyway (instead it's compiled as part of the kernel, and called from the eBPF program, whether it's interpreted or JITted). @pchaignon You mind if I reuse the details you provide for the doc about helpers I'm working on?

Comment: @Qeole Sure! No problem.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.

Comment: Is it possible to disable `ftrace` globally? Also, I read that `bpf_trace_printk()` produces output in `/sys/kernel/` I'm seeing the output of  on console as well as in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe` but I also see it on the console. How do I limit it _only_ in sysfs?